# Sort a partition of an array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I have the following cell array `A` of size 1x9

```
A= {{'O1'} ,{'O1','O2','O3','O4'} ,{'O1','O3'} ,{'O1','O2','O3','O4'} , {},{'O1','O2','O3','O4'},{'O1','O3'},{'O1','O2','O3','O4'},{'O1','O2','O3','O4'}};
```

I want to sort a partition of this cell array starting the fifth element `A{5:9}` according to number of elements in the cell .  I have tried the `sort` function as follows by didn't seems to work

```
[P,I] = sort(cellfun('length',A{5:9}));
A = A(I);
```

Also is there any way to keep track of the original indices of the cellarray after sorting ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sorting can be performed with the following code/

```
A= {{'O1'} ,{'O1','O2','O3','O4'} ,{'O1','O3'} ,{'O1','O2','O3','O4'} , {},

{'O1','O2','O3','O4'},{'O1','O3'},{'O1','O2','O3','O4'},{'O1','O2','O3','O4'}};
disp('Before sorting')
for ii = 1:numel(A)
    fprintf('%d: %s\n',ii, cell2str(A{ii}));
end
a=A(5:end);
[P,I] = sort( cellfun(@(x) numel(x),a) );
A(5:end) = a(I);
clear a

disp('After sorting')
for ii = 1:numel(A)
    fprintf('%d: %s\n',ii, cell2str(A{ii}));
end
```

The mapping between the initial and final order of the cell array can be found using again `I`:

```
originalOrder = 1:numel(A);
finalOrder    = originalOrder;
o = originalOrder(5:end);
finalOrder(5:end) = o(I);
clear o
```

In your case: `finalOrder = [1 2 3 4 5 7 6 8 9]`
The original position of cell `6`in the modified `A` was `finalOrder(6) = 7`.